# REST API design, PATCH a resource object through other resource objects

Tags: database, rest, restful-architecture

I have 3 tables in DB: order_groups, orders and tasks. order_groups to orders is 1-N, orders to tasks is 1-N. tasks has a column "status". Now I want to update status of all tasks belong to a order_group (say ID 3) to a specific value say "DONE". What should the REST API be like? Because eventually I update task objects instead of order_group object. Should it be

```
PATCH /tasks/status  {"op":"REPLACE", "path":"/order_groups/3", "value":"DONE"}
```

or

```
PATCH /order_groups/3 {"op":"REPLACE", "path":"/tasks/status", "value":"DONE"}
```

or

```
PATCH /order_groups/3/tasks {"op":"REPLACE", "path":"/status", "value":"DONE"}
```

or anything better

Comment: I voted to close this question due to the likelihood of attracting opinionated answeres as there is no right or wrong on designing an API. Further it is not a good API design if you solely expose DB tables as  resources anyway IMO. A common misconception is that a URI path tells anything about the relation of resources (i.e. for an URI a/b/c that the content received from c is related to the content of a and/or b) though the relation should be mapped via links and relation names actually. It is therefore up to you which design or what approach you actually prefer.

Comment: Note further that it is technically possible to modify multiple resources with a single PATCH request, though the changes have to be applied atomically. Either all are applied or none at all.

Comment: I do have quite some logic behind the REST API instead of simply exposing DB to REST client. But to client, it's pretty straight forward. As I am the only REST service server side developer on the project I need some confirmation. Thanks Roman for let me know that there might be multiple options. After some more reading I chose the last one.